# Conditional forward fill in dolphindb

Tags: sql-update, dolphindb

To simplify my question, consider the following table in dolphindb:

```
t=table(1..5 as id, 1 NULL 3 NULL NULL as x)
```

I would like to forward fill nulls ONLY for the rows that I specify. For example, only for the row with id=2. I tried the following SQL query but the result was unexpected.

```
update t set x=ffill(x) where id=2
```

The table t was not updated at all. I would appreciate it if someone can point out the mistake in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The 'where' condition in SQL is always executed before the 'select' calculations. Therefore in this case you lose the information about id=1. Try this:

```
update t set x=iif(id==2, ffill(x), x)
```

This uses dolphindb function `iif`. Effectively it is a loop.